# Discord Bot Voice Channel Update

Tags: python, discord, bots

I've been working on a Discord Bot that edits a voice channel with a command.
The Name of the voice channel is named "0" and should increment by 1 when calling the command.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Token des Bots
TOKEN = 'DEIN_BOT_TOKEN'

# ID des Voice-Channels, dessen Namen wir aktualisieren wollen
VOICE_CHANNEL_ID = 'DEINE_VOICE_CHANNEL_ID'

# Startwert
count = 0

# Discord-Client initialisieren mit Intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.voice_states = True  # Hinzugefügt, um auf Voice-Channel-Events zu reagieren
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# Funktion zum Inkrementieren des Zählers und Aktualisieren des Kanalnamens
async def update_channel_name(channel):
    global count
    count += 1
    await channel.edit(name=f"ISO {count}")

# Befehls-Handler für den Befehl "!increment"
@client.command()
async def increment(ctx):
    # Nachricht im Voice-Channel senden
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(int(VOICE_CHANNEL_ID))
    if voice_channel:
        await update_channel_name(voice_channel)
        await ctx.send("Voice-Chat-Name wurde aktualisiert.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Voice-Channel nicht gefunden.")

# Event-Listener für das Bereit-Ereignis
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Eingeloggt als')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------------------')

# Den Bot starten
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I intentionally did not wrote the Tokens.
When running the command !increment nothing really happens and I don't even know what to do rn.

Comment: Please provide more context. Are there any errors thrown? What is actually happening instead of what you expected?

Comment: the bot does not give any hint if its working
```
2024-03-04 20:42:55 WARNING  discord.ext.commands.bot Privileged message content intent is missing, commands may not work as expected.
2024-03-04 20:42:55 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2024-03-04 20:42:56 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 556a096dc34dfb2dc72a71bafa875b5e).
Eingeloggt als
bot
1214251790208475167
------------------
```
this is the output. I really dont know how to fix the Warning output

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable the message content intent in the developer portal. (The settings is on the same page where you can get the bot token)

Comment: Already did that, but still no reaction from the bot

Comment: add a print statement to the beginning of the command to see if the command is even being run